# add dynamic input fields of type file, and preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a dynamic `input of type file` to add or remove a number of images.

[image]

when the user clicks on `add fields` it adds new input of type field. code for appending input fields when button clicked:

```
var i = 0;
    $("#add_more_img").click(function(e){
        i++;
        $("#dynamic_table_field").append('<tr id=row'+i+'><td><button name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove">X</button></td><td><input type="file" name="event_images[]" id="event_images'+i+'" data-panelid="event_images'+i+'" class="form-control images_list" accept="image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg" /></td><td id="img_preview_td"><img name="img_preview'+i+'" id="img_preview" /></td></tr>');
        alert("Hiiiiii");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

when the user select an image, I want it to be displayed inside the red border in the picture above. I already have code for that, but it works only for single input field. So I tried to make some changes on that code, but still did not work. Here is the code:

```
$(".images_list").change(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(input);
        var val = $(this).val();
        switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
            case 'gif': case 'jpg': case 'png': case 'jpeg':
                alert("an image");
                alert(name);
                readURL(this);
                break;
            default:
                $(this).val('');
                // error message here
                alert("not an image");
                break;
        }
    });
    function readURL(input) {
        var this_id = input.attr("id");
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                this_id.attr('src', e.target.result);
                this_id.css({
                    width:"120px",
                    height:"120px"
                });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

I can not display images I chose.

other problem, When I submit the form it did remove all the input fields I added them. how can I prevent this?

thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT:** I added this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bakursait/nrwda826/).

Comment: If you can prepare a js fiddle it will be easier to help.

Comment: @osmanraifgunes .. I added JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a working sample. I tried on my machine and works now.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Title Goes Here</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        #div_create_event {
            margin: 17px 0;
        }

        #img_preview_td {
            outline: 1px solid red;
            width: 70px;
        }

        img {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i = 0;
        $("#add_more_img").click(function(e){
            i++;
            $("#dynamic_table_field").append('<tr id=row'+i+'><td><button name="remove" id="'+i
            +'" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove">X</button></td><td><input type="file" onchange="myfn(this)" name="event_images[]" id="event_images'+i
            +'" data-panelid="event_images'+i+'" class="form-control images_list" accept="image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg" />'
            +'</td><td id="img_preview_td"><img id="img_preview'+i+'" /></td></tr>');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $(document).on("click",".btn-remove",function(){
             var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
             $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
        });
    });

      function myfn(myinput) {
            var name = $(myinput).attr("name");
            var id = $(myinput).attr("id");
            var val = $(myinput).val();
            debugger;
            switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
                case 'gif': case 'jpg': case 'png': case 'jpeg':
                    readURL(myinput);
                    break;
                default:
                    $(this).val('');
                    break;
            }
        }


        function readURL(myinput) {
           debugger;
            if (myinput.files && myinput.files[0]) {
                  var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#img_preview' + $(myinput).attr("id").replace('event_images','') ).attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(myinput.files[0]);
            }
        }


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" name="add_event" id="add_event" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="event_title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="event_title">
        </div>
        <table id="dynamic_table_field">
            <tr>
                <td><button name="add_more_img" id="add_more_img" class="btn btn-success">Add fields</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group" id="div_create_event">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="create_event" name="create_event" value="Add Event">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Form is not posting now.

Comment: thank you for your help, my friend. it works very well. 
one last thing, when I click `submit` it delete all the input fields. my question is how to keep it (and its picture) displayed even after `submit` is clicked?. **I tried to user `e.preventDefault()` but this stop `submit` job**.
thanks again!

Comment: Post sends all this data to server. You should save files to server and then return images and your input field id,name, etc inside your get method. For more help please ask another question and provide your codes.